# Want to know when UIPickerViewDataSource finished

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I save the last user selection in the picker view. But when the view is opened again I do not where to use

```
[pickerView selectRow:lastSelectedRow inComponent:lastSelectedComponent animated:YES];
```

If I use it in `viewDidLoad` the problem is `UIPickerViewDataSource` has not finished yet, so the scrolling is not correct.
I can not find delegate function after `UIPickerViewDataSource` is finished.
Where can I use the above line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `YES` in animated argument, thus I assume you want to see it animated -> you should call this method in `viewDidAppear`, not in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But even in viewDidAppear it does not work, apparently because the view controller main view and subviews including the pickerview did appear, but the data source did not finish yet.